# UEFI How to modify the boot order list programmatically

Tags: uefi

Building a firmware using EDK2, what is the programmatic way to provide a default boot order? I want the default option to be boot from SD card. I have an bootx64.efi image stored in the SD card.

Every time when I build the EDK2 image and flash it on the target, I need to enter boot maintenance manager option and add SD card as boot option and change the boot order.

I looked into the code and read the specifications of Boot manager. I understood that I need to modify Boot Order variable but I don't get how to add SD card option in the source code.

I am looking into the QemubootOrder.c file but I don't understand where I need to add the path to SD card .

Comment: QEMU is special - it lets the user specify the order of boot options, and populate boot options, on the QEMU command line.  See https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/bootindex.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, if your UEFI port considers that SD card a "removable media", which is should - it should automatically load it if it is placed in `\EFI\BOOT\` on the FAT-formatted EFI System Partition.

`BootOrder` comes in if you want to be able to support multiple options. But `BootOrder` itself only consists of a list of the numerical part of the available `Boot####` options, in order of preference.

You can learn more about these mechanisms from the [UEFI](http://uefi.org/specifications) Specification. Current version is 2.6, and the most relevant bit for this topic is section **3.1 Firmware Boot Manager**.